# Exclude files from dependencies in Maven WAR

Tags: java, maven-plugin, tess4j

I am generating a WAR file which is using tess4j. Tess4j contains the following structure:

```
- net.sourceforge.tess4j
- META-INF/
- win32-x86/winlibraries
```

My war project is used in Linux, so I don't need winlibraries inside the tess4j dependency. I want to package my WAR using a version of tess4j without winlibraries, because it take up a lot of size. Is it possible to do using only Maven? Any plugin?

Comment: You could download tess, remove the win libraries and publish it to maven with your own groupId. Then use this in your project.

Comment: yes @Karsten, but It only works on my pc. Dont works in a CI/CD scenario.

Comment: Then you need to use a custom repository in your build. Or, maybe you should just live with these files.

Comment: I'd recommend a company wide Maven artifact repository manager for sharing custom artifacts and plugins. There are [lots of choices](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) today.

Comment: Ok. So the only way is to create a custom tess4j library. Thanks